Blazor : Root component type 'iOSClub.WebSite.Components.Routes' could not be found in the assembly 'iOSClub.WebSite'
When I use Blazor Web project, use:
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveAuto"/>
<AntContainer @rendermode="InteractiveAuto"/>

But it doesn't work at all when I use it
This is the error message I got on the browser.
Error: One or more errors occurred. (Root component type 'iOSClub.WebSite.Components.Routes' could not be found in the assembly 'iOSClub.WebSite'.)

If I use InteractiveServer, I dont see this error.

Check your _Imports.razor file in your client app and make sure you're referencing the correct assemblies from your backend app with a using statement.
